# Handle oracle ORA-04068:existing state of packages has been discarded in Java Application

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql, jdbi

I am getting below error in my PROD environment. Some DB call is working fine but some call is throwing exception due to package is discarded/state is invalidate and many reason. But I don't have control to re-compile package. i.e i have only read-only access. I am using Java8, JDBI and Oracle database with connection pooling.

```
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package body "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program being called: "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
ORA-06512: at line 34
```

I would like do to re-try options(2 times) by handle this exception in catch block and re-try from catch block. I referred many forums, connection has old compiled stored procedure or state of object as dirty. So, If I re-try with fresh connection for 3 times i may not get this error. Please suggest me fresh connection will work or fresh session will work. I am going to try this below

```
public void callDB(int userName, int retryCount) throws Exception {
    try(Handle handle = dbInstance.open()) {
        OutputParameters parameters = handle.createCall(MY_STORED_PROC).bind(0,userName).bind(1,Oracle.CURSOR);
        Employee employee=parameters.getObject(2);          
    } catch(Exception e) {
       logger.error(e);
        if(retryCount!=2 && e.getMessage().contains("ORA-04068")) {
          retryCount=retryCount+1;
          callDB(userName, retryCount);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting from connection pooling via JDBI API. Please let me know this above code will work or not. Or Shall I need to re-try different way.

Also, suggest me when i re-try do i need create a new session or connection from connection pool is enough.

Comment: Jdbi project member here: Jdbi does not provide connection pooling--that comes from whatever DataSource you pass into it. If you create the DBI with a JDBC connection string, then every handle will get a new database connection (i.e. not from a pool).

Comment: Yes. I agree. I am using underlay datasource. I am not passing connection string for each JDBC connection instead i am using connection pool only. Please skip the JDBI context if confused.

Comment: Read this article: [Avoiding ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded](https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/avoiding-ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded/)

Comment: I understand. My question is re-try from java catch block with new connection will work or not?